# Which HTTP Method should I use when sending an instruction to modify the state of an in-memory resource object

Tags: rest, http, methods, process, resources

We want to have an API, which is connected to Real Time Market Data systems and performs financial pricings.
As the pricing depends on those market data (and on parameters sent with the request in order to select the right mathematical model), can we say that the result of the pricing can be considered as a Resource ? Can the "Price" method can be actually a GET ?

We would want also to update the market data configuration to be able to configure the service on the fly (adding new market data systems to plug to).
The "resource" here can be the Market Data Container, but the instruction to modify it is not a resource... So what Http Method could it be ?

Thanks,

Laurent

Comment: Sounds like a `PUT` but I don't know if I understood it well.

Comment: A Put would send a specific model in the query... the model is not the resource we want to modify, we want to send an instruction (which is not a resource at all), but that will have actually an impact on a specific resource (which is all the marketData that are loaded in memory) :) !